# How to Serialize an object of rx.Single returned by a function?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, serialization, rx-java

I am using Spring Framework and trying to cache the results returned by a method using `@Cacheable` annotation.
The method returns an object of `rx.Single class`. I am getting following error when trying to cache the results,

> Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [rx.Single]

How can I proceed to cache the results? or
How can I serialize an object of `rx.Single class`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: **you can't**.

You can create your own class, which will hold all required information and make it `Serializable`.

Comment: I am getting data from another API, which gives data as object of rx.Single<T>, where T is Serializable. I want to cache T from the response. Any leads on it?

Comment: Return `T`  from your method.